# How should container behave when it is disposed?

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

Should it throw an exception, pass resolution to its parent or something else?

My favorite container [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac) raises an exception - which is the only thing I don't like about it.
I think that it should pass resolution to its parent which should resolve my issue with this code

```
    class LazyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }

    class SomeClass
    {
        public event EventHandler WatchOut = (s, ea) => { };
        public void Start()
        {
            WatchOut(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    class LazyInterceptor
    {
        Lazy<LazyClass> lazy;
        public LazyInterceptor(Lazy<LazyClass> lazy)
        {
            this.lazy = lazy;
        }
        public void Register(SomeClass some)
        {
            some.WatchOut += (s, ea) => lazy.Value.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LazyAndEvents()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<LazyClass>().SingleInstance();
        var container = builder.Build();

        var someClass = new SomeClass();

        using (var inner = container.BeginLifetimeScope(cb => 
            cb.RegisterType().SingleInstance()))
        {
            var interceptor = inner.Resolve();
            interceptor.Register(someClass);
        }

        someClass.Start();
    }
```

I know of three workarounds around this, but they all seem just wrong

- not disposing container - this is what I currently do, but that's just to make Autofac happy
- explicitly registering lazy - seems just wrong and I don't even know what will be resolved
- taking ownership for dispose - it doesn't seem as bad, but I don't use object in that way, so again it looks like a workaround. Also, in Autofac it introduces dependency which is not nice

Comment: Hi Rikard- your first solution, not disposing the container, sounds like the right one without more info. If you don't want the instances disposed, why dispose the container? As Peter points out, that's pretty much the sole purpose of `Container.Dispose()`. Cheers!

Comment: I feel like there is clearly something wrong here. I use scope in this case as configuration point where I gather all dependencies, resolve them and set up behavior. At this point container fulfilled it's purpose. It has resolved all instances from the graph based on their dependencies. I have no further use for it. I don't want behavior of those instances to be dependent on that scope lifetime. So it feels like I'm leaking scope by not disposing it. And clearly, factories and lazy are dependent on scope lifetime which I think they shouldn't be. Bottom line: I feel that design is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps we need to come up with an alternative configuration mechanism for your scenario? Sounds like scopes are the wrong thing to use, but I see that you need some of their features. Are you looking for something that controls the visibility of components, separately from their lifetime? Thanks for the data!

Comment: I need most if not all of their features. If I have disposable components I would like them to be disposed when scope is disposed. If they are not disposable I would like for container to redirect their lazy/factory resolves to it's parent scope after it is disposed. Why is better to throw exception than to redirect? Clearly, my scenario is not supported. If specific component is registered in that scope it will throw NotRegisteredException - which should be ok. If that scope overrides parent scope than there will be suspicious behavior, but I would prefer that, because it would be consistent.

Comment: The problem with the "redirect" is that you would have to introduce a proxy or interceptor on these instances. There is a level of complexity here that I do not see any real benefit from.

Comment: Well, if that were true I wouldn't complain. But because I proposed a two line solution to Nick I know that it's doable and won't introduce any complexity. I guess I didn't explain very well what I was trying to do, so he was reluctant to change that behavior. This is a second attempt at that ;)

Comment: I think my proposed solution is even less code than yours... :) i.e. don't call Dispose() on the child scope. Not calling Dispose() is safer than a redirect, as it avoids the potential for a reference leak once you start creating instances in the parent container. Best of luck with it, hope things come out clean and simple otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of lifetime scopes is that to control the *lifetime* of the contained instances. Building on the Disposable pattern, disposing the container is a clean and well-established way of releasing the resources governed by that container. Thus, when a lifetime scope is disposed you should no longer depend on instances resolved from that lifetime scope.

So I would say that you are definitively using Autofac the wrong way here. Perhaps if you explained why you want to use the scope like that, we could figure out the proper usage.

Comment: The issue here is that LazyClass is live in root container. It's lifetime scope is not disposed. Lifetime scope of LazyInterceptor is disposed, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: It is still not clear to me why you resolve the interceptor from a new lifetime scope.

Comment: Because it should be in it's own scope. It's separate part of the system and it shouldn't be resolvable from anywhere else.

Comment: Bottom line is: you can use scope for restricting resolves, but you *must* keep it around as long as the instances should live. This is by design.